# Java Spring Application JDBC database url

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, jdbc

I'm a bit rusty on my java and am new to the JDBC connection process. My friend sent me a small spring app he was having trouble with.

All I need to do is pull a few columns from the SQL database and display them on the page. I have the following code for my JDBC connection.

```
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("Connected to database!");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://${jdbc.host}";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "sa", "");

    stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,description,price FROM products ");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next())
    {
        Product prod = new Product();
        prod.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        prod.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
        prod.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
        products.add(prod);
    }
```

My question is regarding the database URL that was given. It was in another file with other jdbc properties. It said that `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://${jdbc.host}` is the URL but this doesn't appear to look like other database URL's I have found on my searches. I feel like I should replace the `{jdbc.host}` with something else, but I have no idea what that might be.

Is this correct? Or is there another way of getting the URL? I'm assuming that's my problem because I feel really confident in the rest of the code that would occur after I pulled the data from the database.

Comment: if that properties file has the details you want, you should read that properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) jdbc.host needs to be present in the properties file along with other properties
2) this property file needs to be mentioned in the application context.xml file and be read using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

When the application context is loaded it reads from this property file and so in this code when it tries to do a ${jdbc.host} it gets it from the context as it is available in the memory.

You do not have to make any code change if the above two things are checked.

Comment: I guess that would make sense, so for the jdbc.host value it says localhost. Would I also specify the port there as well? I'm using Tomcat on localhost:8080 so I would change it to localhost:8080, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the ${jdbc.host} value is getting read from an external properties file. Search for `jdbc.host` in your project and you will find the actual value assuming you have the properties file inside your project folder.